# Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found for excel

Tags: php, com

I am using COM to initiate a Excel file, it works on my one machine A but doesnt work well in another machine. And when it is uploaded to the production server , it has the same issue again. What is the possible causes and solution to solve it?

I am using the latest php , window 7.

Answer (score 0):

Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found for excel

above line indicates that class COM not found for object that you have initiated.
so check whether you have included class file or not.

On your local machine it's not giving error doesn't mean its working fine.
It may happen that error reporting is off at local machine and on live server it is ON.

So, I advise please enable error reporting at local machine and have a look.

you can enable error reporting through php.ini file or in your php code as following,

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Where can i get the class file? isn't it part of the function? @amar gharat